Llamar métodos en Java
tengo este código y quiero llamar en el main a los métodos pero no se como. Muchas gracias.
Esta es la primera clase de tipo Plantas.
public class Plantas {

    private String nombre;
    private double tamanio;
    private String color;
    private double precio;

    public Plantas(String nombre, double tamanio, String color, double precio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tamanio = tamanio;
        this.color = color;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getTamanio() {
        return tamanio;
    }

    public void setTamanio(double tamanio) {
        this.tamanio = tamanio;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Planta: " +
                "nombre: " + nombre + '\'' +
                ", tamaño: " + tamanio + "cm " +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", precio=" + precio + " € " +
                '}';
    }
}

Aquí estoy creando una clase para manejar una LinkedList.
package Ejercicio4;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class manejoLinkedList extends Plantas {

    private List<Plantas> listaPlantas;

    public manejoLinkedList(String nombre, double tamanio, String color, double precio) {
        super(nombre, tamanio, color, precio);
        this.listaPlantas = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public double precioMedio() {
        double mediaPlantas = 0;
        for (Plantas plantas : listaPlantas) {
            mediaPlantas = plantas.getPrecio() / listaPlantas.size();
        }
        return mediaPlantas;
    }

    public double precioMaximo() {
        double precio = 0;
        for (Plantas plantas : listaPlantas) {
            if (precio < plantas.getPrecio()) {
                precio = plantas.getPrecio();

            }
        }
        return precio;
    }

    public double precioMinimo() {
        double precio = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Plantas plantas : listaPlantas) {
            if (precio < plantas.getPrecio()) {
                precio = plantas.getPrecio();
            }
        }
        return precio;
    }
}

En el tester es donde precioMedio y eso no se llamarlo desde las otras clases.
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<manejoLinkedList> listaPlantas = new LinkedList<>();

        manejoLinkedList planta = new manejoLinkedList( "margarita", 12.3, "blanca", 25.3 );
        manejoLinkedList planta1 = new manejoLinkedList( "Amapola", 22.3, "rosa", 6.32 );
        manejoLinkedList planta2 = new manejoLinkedList( "Rosa", 10.3, "roja", 2 );
        manejoLinkedList planta3 = new manejoLinkedList( "Jazmín", 28.37, "blanco", 5.35 );

        listaPlantas.add( planta );
        listaPlantas.add( planta1 );
        listaPlantas.add( planta2 );
        listaPlantas.add( planta3 );

        System.out.println(listaPlantas);
    }
}


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! uh para que confusion... tenes una clase que maneja una lista pero no tiene un metodo para agregar a la lista.. despues generas objetos de esa clase y los agregas a una lista.. no se como decia tu ejercicio, pero algo suena muy raro.. para llamar a un metodo, es obj.metodo()... pero aca, tus objetos estan dentro de una lista...

Su clase Plantas queda casi igual, solamente le cambiamos el nombre de Plantas a Planta para seguir con la convención.
Empecemos por el main, para que funciones más o menos lo que tenías necesitas saber que tienes una lista de plantas y eso hace que compile y haga más o menos lo que esperamos el código
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Planta> listaPlantas = new LinkedList<>();

        Planta planta = new Planta( "margarita", 12.3, "blanca", 25.3 );
        Planta planta1 = new Planta( "Amapola", 22.3, "rosa", 6.32 );
        Planta planta2 = new Planta( "Rosa", 10.3, "roja", 2 );
        Planta planta3 = new Planta( "Jazmín", 28.37, "blanco", 5.35 );

        listaPlantas.add( planta );
        listaPlantas.add( planta1 );
        listaPlantas.add( planta2 );
        listaPlantas.add( planta3 );

        System.out.println(listaPlantas);
        // el código para calcular máximo y mínimo irá acá
    }
}

Ahora para hacer los cálculos tenemos varias opciones. En mi opinión la opción más fácil es usar el API de stream de la siguiente manera:
IntSummaryStatistics estadisticaBasica = listaPlantas.stream()
        .mapToDouble(Planta::getPrecio)
        .summaryStatistics();
 
double min = estadisticaBasica.getMin();
double max = estadisticaBasica.getMax();

System.out.println("El preio máximo es:" + max);
System.out.println("El preio mínimo es:" + min);


Hay bastante lío y confusión en tu código. Veamos punto por punto:

La clase manejoLinkedList no tiene por qué extender de Plantas. La herencia es algo metafísico, o sea, lo que debería determinarla es si el objeto es un tipo de. El manejo de una lista de plantas NO es una planta. De Planta podría extender un Eucalipto, un Mango, una Manzana, pero NO un clase destinada a manejar plantas. Por cierto, respeta la convención de nombre1 en Java. Parece una tontería, pero ayuda bastante a entender el código. Según dicha convención, las clases deberían tener nombres en sustantivo y por lo general en singular y los métodos deben empezar por verbos. Pensando en la vida real, podemos preguntarnos ¿qué es lo que guarda una serie de plantas? ¡Pues es un Vivero! Ese es el sustantivo para nuestra clase, evitando darle el nombre de un método: manejo...
Si lo que maneja una lista de plantas es un Vivero. Entonces, vamos a crear esa clase, la cual tendrá un constructor que recibirá en parámetro la lista de plantas y es desde esa clase que obtendremos el precio medio de las plantas que hay en el vivero, etc.

Con esas dos aproximaciones ya tienes una idea clara de las cosas y todo planteado desde un punto de vista conforme a la realidad y sin herencias innecesarias.
El código quedaría así, aplicando además una convención de nombre correcta.
VER DEMO.
Planta
public class Planta {

    private String nombre;
    private double tamanio;
    private String color;
    private double precio;

    public Planta(String nombre, double tamanio, String color, double precio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tamanio = tamanio;
        this.color = color;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getTamanio() {
        return tamanio;
    }

    public void setTamanio(double tamanio) {
        this.tamanio = tamanio;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Planta: " +
                "nombre: " + nombre + '\'' +
                ", tamaño: " + tamanio + "cm " +
                ", color='" + color + '\'' +
                ", precio=" + precio + " € " +
                '}';
    }
}

Vivero
 public class Vivero {

    private List<Planta> listaPlantas;

    public Vivero(List<Planta> listaPlantas) {
        this.listaPlantas=listaPlantas;
    }

    public double precioMedio() {
        double mediaPlantas = 0;
        for (Planta planta : listaPlantas) {
            mediaPlantas = planta.getPrecio() / listaPlantas.size();
        }
        return mediaPlantas;
    }

    public double precioMaximo() {
        double precio = 0;
        for (Planta planta : listaPlantas) {
            if (precio < planta.getPrecio()) {
                precio = planta.getPrecio();
            }
        }
        return precio;
    }

    public double precioMinimo() {
        double precio = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Planta planta : listaPlantas) {
            if (precio < planta.getPrecio()) {
                precio = planta.getPrecio();
            }
        }
        return precio;
    }
} 

Tester
class Tester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Planta> listaPlantas = new LinkedList<>();
        listaPlantas.add(new Planta( "margarita", 12.3, "blanca", 25.3 ));
        listaPlantas.add(new Planta( "Amapola", 22.3, "rosa", 6.32 ));
        listaPlantas.add(new Planta( "Rosa", 10.3, "roja", 2 ));
        listaPlantas.add(new Planta( "Jazmín", 28.37, "blanco", 5.35 ));

        Vivero mVivero=new Vivero(listaPlantas);
        System.out.printf("Precio medio: %.2f%n",mVivero.precioMedio());
        System.out.printf("Precio máximo: %.2f%n",mVivero.precioMaximo());
    }  
}


Notas

Para más detalles sobre la convención de nombre consulta las respuestas a la  pregunta: ¿Cuál es la convención para escribir variables en Java?


Joe que buena respuesta, muchas gracias.
